# SQL - Groups rows that share a value in different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has the following fields

```
SalesOrderID RelatedOrderID Amount
1            0              5.00
2            1              1.00
3            0              3.00
4            0              20.00
5            4              10.00
```

I'm looking to write a query that will return the sales order total made up of the original total and the RelatedOrderID total.

```
SalesOrderID NewAmount
1            6.00
4            30.00
```

Hope that makes sense...please ask any questions. I'm aware it's a confusing situation!

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Why is sales order ID 3 excluded from your expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `union all` and then aggregate::

```
select SalesOrderID, sum(amount) as amount
from ((select SalesOrderID,  amount from t) union all
      (select RelatedSalesOrderID, amount from t where RelatedSalesOrderID > 0)
     ) tt
group by SalesOrderID;
```

Answer (score 0):

For that effect you will have to use something like this

```
SELECT
    least(o.SalesOrderId,r.SalesOrderId) AS SalesOrderId,
    o.Amount + r.Amount AS Amount
FROM
    orders o
JOIN orders r ON o.SalesOrderId = r.RelatedOrderID;
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks both, I've actually worked it out since posting this:

```
SELECT so1.SalesOrderID,
cast(SUM(so1.Amount+so2.Amount) as money) as NewAmount
FROM SalesOrder so1
JOIN SalesOrder so2
ON so1.SalesOrderID = so2.RelatedOrderID
GROUP BY so1.sorder_code
```

Comment: This makes no sense.  I fail to see how this returns the desired results.

Comment: apologies, I posted a previous query. Updated.

Comment: And likewise this makes no sense.  You are trying to *add* numbers.  Where does the `-` come in?  This does not return the values specified in the question.

Comment: Alright, if you switch - for + it does what I need. Since writing this I went on to change my requirements. The logic still works even if the operator has changed